# If $a^x=bc$, $b^y=ca$ and....

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a^x=bc$, $b^y=ca$ and $c^z=ab$, prove that: $xyz=x+y+z+2$.

My Approach;
Here,

$$a^x=bc$$
$$a={bc}^{\frac {1}{x}}$$

and,

$$b={ca}^{\frac {1}{y}}$$
$$c={ab}^{\frac {1}{z}}$$

I got stopped from here. Please help me to continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

We have $$abc=a^{x+1}=b^{y+1}=c^{z+1}=K\text{(say)}$$

$\implies a=K^{1/(x+1)}$ etc.

Put the values of $a,b,c$  in one of $a^x=bc, b^y=ca,c^z=ab$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

> \begin{align*} x &= \frac{\log b+\log c}{\log a} \\[7pt] (B+C)(C+A)(A+B) &= BC(B+C)+CA(C+A)+AB(A+B)+2ABC \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Notice here, quite simple approach...

$a^x.b^y.c^z=(bc).(ca).(ab)$
$a^x.b^y.c^z=a^2.b^2.c^2$

Comparing the corresponding exponents...
$x=y=z=2$.

Now,
Ĺ.H.S$=xyz =2\times 2\times 2=8$

R.H.S$=x+y+z+2=2+2+2+2=8$ 
Proved.

.....))

Comment: Can you please explain your logic. How does $a^xb^yc^z=a^2b^2c^2$ imply $x=y=z=2$? For example, $1^22^24^2=1^{18}2^14^{5/2}$ but the exponents do not match.

Comment: This answer is wrong, The counterexample of @alex shows this.

Comment: @Alex, If the bases are same the exponents must be equal...to retain the equality

Comment: @occasionaluser That is not true, see my counter example above.

Comment: @Alex, I have seen.  but if the bases are same then can't we equate the powers